# Why javascript check type in null case even use ==

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, types, compare

I am confused little bit about == and ===. I know == means not check type and === means check with type. but when I apply with **null** case then it fail. why

```
var obj = {
    name : 'null'
}

document.write(obj.name==null);
```

output: false

see link
http://plnkr.co/edit/PnxL6hJOep3AN1Tgrafn?p=preview

Comment: `'null'` and `null` are not the same thing

Comment: no i can't do like this. because it's coming from backend

Comment: but == not check type

Comment: @Rahul yes, but in JS, `'1'==1` returns `true`. So why does `'null'==null` return `false`?

Comment: @JeremyThille  ECMAScript 5 specification says :

1) For '1' == 1: Rule is: If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y: "2" == 2.                                                                                                                    

2) For 'null' == null: Rule is: If Type(x) is either String or Number and Type(y) is Object, return the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y): ToPrimitive means implicit valueOf call or toString if toString is defined and valueOf is not.

Comment: @VishalRajole Your comment worth typing in the answer area! :)

Comment: @TareqMahmood Thanks. I updated my answer. If it is helpful, please accept it as answer.

Comment: @VishalRajole, but I am not the OP here to accept.

Answer (score 3):

That's because in your code, `obj.name` is a string containing `"null"`. The `==` operator doesn't parse strings containing anything that isn't a number. For example, `false != "false"`.

The following will work:

```
var obj = {
    name: null
};

document.write(obj.name == null); // true
```

Comment: That's the whole point of the question. `==` doesn't check for type, for instance : `'1'==1` returns `true` (!) So why does `'null'==null` return `false`?

Comment: `==` only parses numbers out of strings.

Comment: Well that's the answer OP is looking for :)

Comment: can you provide any documentation relate this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators "When comparing a number and a string, the string is converted to a number value. JavaScript attempts to convert the string numeric literal to a Number type value. First, a mathematical value is derived from the string numeric literal. Next, this value is rounded to nearest Number type value."

Answer (score 1):

ECMAScript 5 specification says :

1) **For '1' == 1: Rule is:** If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y: "2" == 2.

2) **For 'null' == null: Rule is:** If Type(x) is either String or Number and Type(y) is Object, return the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y): ToPrimitive means implicit valueOf call or toString if toString is defined and valueOf is not.

For complete list of Coercion rules, visit: 
http://webreflection.blogspot.in/2010/10/javascript-coercion-demystified.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are comparing null to the string 'null' and getting the correct false

```
var obj = {
name : null
}

document.write(obj.name===null);    true

var obj = {
name : 'null'
}

document.write(obj.name==='null');  true

var obj = {
    name : null
}

document.write(obj.name=='null');  false

var obj = {
name : 'null'
}

document.write(obj.name=='null'); true
```